# Can entities be deleted without the ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using the default code generated entities with Entity Framework, is there a way to delete an entity object without using the ObjectContext? For example, self-tracking entities have a `MarkAsDeleted` method. Also, the ObjectContext isn't needed to update or add objects, so I'm hoping the same applies to deleting objects.

One thing that doesn't work is to simply mark the entity as deleted since the property is readonly:

```
foo.EntityState = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Comment: This goes against the concept of _Unit Of Work_. We might be able give you an alternative solution if you can describe the situation you are facing.

Comment: @Eranga: What about answering the question if you know the answer?

Comment: @Ludo the answer to your question is "No".

Comment: Why would you do that? You can just execute a sql statement that deletes a row/rows in your database but if you have more advanced mapping strategies it may make your database corrupt from EF point of view. Again, it would be interesting to understand the scenario where you need something like this.

Comment: @Pawel: might as well ask me why I use EF (which would be equally unhelpful).

Comment: @Ludo don't bite the hand that feeds you.

Comment: @MattGreer: if you don't see how the above comments are unhelpful and a tad condescending I'll just have to disagree with you; furthermore I'm not about extremes: I try to behave as politely as I would in person (not more aggressively, but not less), and that's the only "rule" I follow; but even in real life this is how I deal with devs from time to time.

Comment: @Ludo I honestly didn't see anything wrong with the other comments. But your attitude turned me off immediately. Don't forget you're asking for help from other human beings who would be volunteering their time to help you. Being nice in this situation can go a long way.

Comment: @MattGreer: yes fine let's just disagree... that's fine really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to be no, so I'm using a technique I wrote about before to attach the `ObjectContext` to all entities that need to delete child entities: http://sixfeetsix.blogspot.com/2012/06/provide-entityobjects-access-to-their.html